# Windows 7: service pack already installed... or not

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I have Windows 7 Ultimate, with SP1 installed... or so I think. What I mean is that, when I go to "Start / Computer" and right-click and choose "Properties", what I get is "Windows 7 Ultimate. (C) Microsoft Corporation etc., etc. Service Pack 1"...

...And yet, when I go to Windows Update, I see that one of the available updates I have is a "Service pack 1" (KB976932). I install it, and it works... but it doesn't ask me to reboot my computer, and the next time I check Windows Update, the SP1 update is still there.

EDIT: I executed "winver.exe" and what I got was: *"Microsoft Windows Version 6.1 (compilation 7600; Service Pack 1)"*. I should also mention that I discovered this when I tried to upgrade to IE 11 (which requires SP1) and the installer failed.

So... do I have SP1 installed or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this options:

1. Clean up temporary files and registry key issues with a free tool like [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), and try to reinstall SP1 update.
2. Download [off-line version of Windows 7 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842)  and try to install it.
3. Try to [update microsoft update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2887535), and try again the update.

   Notes:
   It is recommended you verify your version of windows going to Computer > right-click properties.
   Also you can check it out if you go to Start > type "cmd" in the search box > type "winver" in cmd. On the version, you will also see if you have the service pack 1 or no.
   Please let me know if you still need help or if you solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but from what I remember, I installed SP1 precisely using the offline installer. I'm editing my question now to add what I got from winver.exe.

Comment: please, that would be helpful. so maybe I can give you a better answer.